# Create all permutations for two vectors in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Thank you for your reply.

Apologies for my poorly presented code. I am fairly new using R.

The idea is to seek for all Y and N combinations for penalty, no penalty and money fine.

The following code provides the structure that I require.

```
s <- c('penalty','no penalty','money fine', 'Community_service')
n <- c('Y','N')

setNames(expand.grid(n, n, n,n), s)
#>    penalty no penalty money fine Community_service
#> 1        Y          Y          Y                 Y
#> 2        N          Y          Y                 Y
#> 3        Y          N          Y                 Y
#> 4        N          N          Y                 Y
#> 5        Y          Y          N                 Y
#> 6        N          Y          N                 Y
#> 7        Y          N          N                 Y
#> 8        N          N          N                 Y
#> 9        Y          Y          Y                 N
#> 10       N          Y          Y                 N
#> 11       Y          N          Y                 N
#> 12       N          N          Y                 N
#> 13       Y          Y          N                 N
#> 14       N          Y          N                 N
#> 15       Y          N          N                 N
#> 16       N          N          N                 N
```

However, when I add a new category in vector s, I get only 16 combinations instead of 26. I wonder what should I add in this code for making work?

```
s <- c('penalty','no penalty','money fine', 'Community_service')
n <- c('Y','N')

setNames(expand.grid(n, n, n,n), s)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be 8 combinations? It's grouped, so it's just 2 * 2 * 2. If so, it's `expand.grid(penalty = n, no_penalty = n, money_fine = n)`

Comment: In other words: where's Y Y Y and N N N gone?